Evaluation leaks in calling N[] on held expressions
Calling N[] on a held expression converts the numbers it contains to approximate numbers (unless an argument is protect by NHoldAll etc.):
Hold[Sqrt[3]] // N
Hold[Sin[3 + 4*5]] // N
(*
   Hold[Sqrt[3.]]
   Hold[Sin[3. + 4. 5.]]
*)

Note that none of Plus, Times, Sqrt, or Sin is evaluated, which is what I think is the expected behavior.
But I discovered that if the expression contains Integrate[..], then N@Integrate[..] is evaluated, even if the Integrate[] code takes a long time or has side effects.
Clear[f];
Hold[Sin[3] + 
    Integrate[f = Sin[x y z], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}]] // 
  N // AbsoluteTiming
f
(*
   {7.17336, Hold[Sin[3.] + 10.8042]}
   Sin[x y z]  <-- value of f
*)

Then I further discovered Power is another function like Integrate. While Sqrt[3] wasn't evaluated above, Power[3, 1/2] is:
HoldComplete[Power[3, 1/2]] // N
(*  HoldComplete[1.73205]  *)

More examples:
x = 3;
Hold[Power[x, 1/2]] // N
Hold[Power[2 x, 1/2]] // N
(*
   Hold[x^0.5]
   Hold[2.44949]
*)

Clear[x, y];
Hold[Sin[x = 3*4*5]] // N
Hold[Sin[y = 3*4*5]^2] // N
{x, y}
(*
   Hold[Sin[x = 3. 4. 5.]]
   Hold[0.0929095]
{x, 60.}
*)

The same behavior occurs in all examples above if Hold is replaced by HoldComplete.
Questions:

Is this behavior documented? (I couldn't find anything about it.)

If so, is there a list of functions that are evaluated in N@Hold[expr]?

Or is the leaky evaluation a bug?

Am I supposed to be using Inactivate[] on the integral or some delicate combination of Hold and Inactivate if I want the arguments held? Note that the following is not highly satisfactory:
Hold[Power[2 x, 1/2]] // ReplaceAll[Power -> Inactive[Power]] // N // 
 ReplaceAll[Inactive[Power] -> Power]
(*  Hold[(2. x)^(1./2.^1.)]  *)




I'm seeing this in the documentation for N: "N converts each successive argument of any function it encounters to numerical form, unless the head of the function has an attribute such as NHoldAll."    Attributes[Power] doesn't have NHoldAll.

@CraigCarter I expect Hold[Power[3, 1/2]] // N to be converted to Hold[Power[3., 0.5]] based on that description. But it's not.

Continued: However, Unprotect[Power]; SetAttributes[Power, {NHoldAll}]; HoldComplete[Power[3, 1/2]] // N  still has the same "leaky behavior".

You're right. I agree.

The behavior of Power is introduced in v8: https://i.sstatic.net/rOD060kZ.png https://i.sstatic.net/nMynH4PN.png That of Integrate is more long-standing, it seems to be there from the beginning: https://i.sstatic.net/bZEE22WU.png Then it gets worse at v2 or v3: https://i.sstatic.net/nvZVylPN.png Then the v1.2 behavior is back in v5: https://i.sstatic.net/DCX6Sp4E.png https://i.sstatic.net/Ddengss4.png

Not really an answer, but WL has been always great in being able to work around its shortcomings, e.g. , just define a simple NSuperHold function returning an held expression with N applied:
NSuperHold = Function[z, Activate[N[Hold[z] /. (Map[#1 -> Inactive[#1] & ])[Cases[HoldComplete[z], f_Symbol /; Context[f] === "System\", {2, Infinity}, Heads -> True]]]], HoldAllComplete];
NSuperHold[(2*x)^(1/2)] // EchoEvaluation;
NSuperHold[Sin[3] + Integrate[f = Sin[xyz], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}]]`
